# Prove or disprove: if $f(n)=\Theta(g^2(n))$ then $\log f(n)=\Theta(\log g(n))$

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

Prove or disprove:

> $f,g:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ are increasing functions.
>
> if $f(n)=\Theta(g^2(n))$ then $\log f(n)=\Theta(\log g(n))$

I think $\log g^2(n)=2\log g(n)$ so $\log f(n) =\Theta(2\log g(n)$.

Therefore the claim is true.

Comment: @AlexProvost the proof seems wrong to me. You can't just log both sides of an equation, and switch the log with the theta (well at least you need to explain why)

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes, I did comment quite hastily. Agreed.

Comment: @AlexProvost I added the details to the premise of the question. If we know that $f,g$ are increasing functions as is $\log$ then the proof should be ok, no?

Comment: You never mention the definition of theta or why the fact they're increasing should matter. Add details

Comment: This is a research opportunity! You have a type of manipulation your intuition tells you is true, but you are unsure about it -- this is a great time to learn how to use more precise tools to justify your intuition, or even try to conjecture and prove a theorem about this sort of manipulation!

Comment: @Hurkyl It's just that I'm not sure what the problem is with my current proof.  Both functions and $\log$ are increasing so the relation must continue